# How to use WHERE inside sub SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to sub-select from a table of `users` .

But I get an error saying
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS n1 ) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 7`

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong here

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 
               n1.userid,
               n1.country,
               n1.gender
               FROM users 
               WHERE n1.country = 'US' 
               AND n1.gender = '1' AS n1 )
```

Comment: put the `AS n1` after the `)`

Comment: `mysql` and `tsql` tags are, as a rule, incompatible. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT n1.userid, n1.country,  n1.gender
      FROM users n1
      WHERE n1.country = 'US' AND n1.gender = '1' 
     ) n1;
```

`as` doesn't belong in the `WHERE` clause.  You need `n1` as a table alias in the subquery, if you are going to use it to qualify column names.  And, you should give the outer query a table alias.

Note:  Obviously the subquery is not needed, but I am guessing you really do want it for your actual problem.

Comment: Might be easier to understand if `n1` isn't used as two differently scoped aliases (I tend to avoid that where possible, and OP is not fluent...)

Answer (score 1):

You did put the alias at the false place. Try

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
               n1.userid,
               n1.country,
               n1.gender
               FROM users AS n1  -- <AS n1> this should be here
               WHERE n1.country = 'US' 
               AND n1.gender = '1')
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
               n1.userid,
               n1.country,
               n1.gender
               FROM users 
               WHERE n1.country = 'US' 
               AND n1.gender = '1') AS n1  -- or here
```

However, if the query isn't just a simplified form, the whole query can also be written without the subquery:

```
SELECT userid, country, gender
FROM users 
WHERE country = 'US' 
AND gender = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like below since that `AS n1` refers to inline view alias. Again, you are trying to use the same alias to refer your column in subquery that's another mistake.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 
               userid,
               country,
               gender
               FROM users 
               WHERE country = 'US' 
               AND gender = '1') AS n1
```